# How to prove $\mathcal{F}(u\ast v)=\mathcal{F}(u)\mathcal{F}(v)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

If $u,v$ are a couples of distributions with compact supports,namely $u,v\in S^{'} $,then How to prove that $$\mathcal{F}(u\ast v)=\mathcal{F}(u)\mathcal{F}(v)$$
$\mathcal{F} $ denote the Fourier transform.

My attempt:I have known that
$$(\mathcal{F}(u),v)=(u,\mathcal{F}(v)),u\in S',v\in S$$
$$(u\ast v,w)=(u,p),p(x)=(v,\tau_{-x}w)$$
However,I don't know how to define the product of distributions.

Comment: Not sure how much this helps but: 
 https://class.ece.uw.edu/235dl/EE235/Project/lesson17/lesson17.html#:~:text=We've%20just%20shown%20that,convolution%20by%20using%20Fourier%20Transforms.

Comment: If $u,v$ have compact support then $\mathcal{F}(u),\mathcal{F}(v)$ are ordinary functions.

Comment: And then $\mathcal{F}(u)(\xi) = \langle u(x), e^{-i\xi x} \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u,v$ have compact support, then so does $u*v$. Also, $\hat{u},\hat{v}$ are ordinary functions given by
$$
\hat{u}(\xi) = \langle u(x), e^{-ix\xi}\rangle \\
\hat{v}(\xi) = \langle u(y), e^{-iy\xi}\rangle 
$$

Therefore,
$$
(\hat{u}\hat{v})(\xi)
= \langle u(x), e^{-ix\xi} \rangle \langle v(y), e^{-iy\xi} \rangle
= \langle u(x), \langle v(y), e^{-iy\xi} \rangle e^{-ix\xi} \rangle
= \langle u(x), \langle v(y), e^{-iy\xi} e^{-ix\xi} \rangle \rangle
= \langle u(x), \langle v(y), e^{-i(x+y)\xi} \rangle \rangle
= \langle (u*v)(t), e^{-it\xi} \rangle \rangle
= \widehat{u*v}(\xi)
.
$$

Comment: Why 'if $u$, $v$ have compact support, then $\mathcal{F}(u)$,$\mathcal{F}{v} $ are odinary functions and $\mathcal{F}(u)(\xi)=\langle u(x),e^{-i\xi \cdot x}\rangle $' is true? Can you give me some reference?

Comment: @Mr.xue. [A recent Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3588829/168433) I'm not sure if any of the proofs is valid, but I know that the statement is. Also, Theorem 12.3 in [Hasse Carlsson's lecture notes](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf) says it.